# How to declare recursive enums with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to experiment with recursive enums in Swift 2 however I'm getting compilation errors.

I started off trying to define my own example:

```
enum Tree {
    case Empty
    indirect case Node(value: Int, left: Tree, right: Tree)
}
```

But get an error: "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by :".

So, I tried Apple's own example from their WWDC15 *What's New in Swift* presentation:

```
enum Tree<T> {
  case Leaf(T)
  indirect case Node(Tree, Tree) 
}
```

But its the same compilation error with this also. If I create a new playground and paste these lines in then it results in the error - see screenshot, or if in an Xcode project same thing, see other screenshot.

I'm using Xcode 7.0.

How come I can't even get Apple's example to compile?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, they said it's coming but not there yet

Comment: right, in that talk Lattner mentioned that the 'indirect' keyword didn't make it into Beta 1 (but is coming soon)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_4/Xcode_7_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf), support for this was added in Xcode 7 beta 4, which states:

> Enums and cases can be marked indirect, which causes the associated
>   value for the enum to be stored indirectly, allowing for recursive
>   data structures to be defined.

The following code works in a Playground:

```
enum Tree {
    case Empty
    indirect case Node(value: Int, left: Tree, right: Tree)
}

let tree1 = Tree.Node(value: 0, left: Tree.Empty, right: Tree.Empty)
let tree2 = Tree.Node(value: 0, left: Tree.Node(value: -1, Tree.Empty, Tree.Empty), right: Tree.Empty)
```

Anecdotally, trying to use the enum with a `switch` worked fine, but using the new Swift 2 `if case` syntax repeatedly crashed Xcode and made the Playground unusable. I'm not sure if this is related specifically to enums or just general beta instability.

---

Background:

At the time this question was originally asked and this answer accepted, Xcode beta1 was the latest release. Xcode 7 beta1—beta3 did not support this and their release notes contained the following verbiage:

> “indirect” enum elements are not yet implemented yet in this beta,
>   they will be added in a later update.

Comment: Thanks for the update about Xcode 7 beta 2. Was wondering about it.

Comment: Is it possible to get the parent for a given node?

Comment: Not as given. I suppose you could add a `parent` member to Node if you made it mutable, but this feels weird to me. See this discussion on implementing a doubly-linked list in Haskell, which is a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386616/how-to-implement-doubly-linked-lists -- If you are processing a `Tree` recursively you should have a reference to the parent and child nodes before you recurse, so you may just need to change your algorithm a bit. If you need a fuller discussion try posting a question.