# Haskell Doubly Linked List Functor

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, functor

I created an instance of `Functor` for the following definition of a `DoubeList` (doubly linked list) data type recently. ([Motivated by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386616/how-to-implement-doubly-linked-lists)) My goal was to define an instance of Functor so that the function `f` in `fmap f db` is applied to the first field in each node in the doubly linked list - regardless of which value constructor is passed to `fmap`. Afterward, I was having trouble explaining to myself how my `fmap` definition would actually evaluate.

For example, passing in some value constructed with `LeftEnd` will result in `fmap` on a `Middle` or `RightEnd`. Likewise, a `fmap` on some value with a `Middle` or `RightEnd` constructor will result in an `fmap` on a previous or next node - and so on and so forth.

However, after exploring the result of fmapping on `LeftEnd`, `MiddleEnd` or `RightEnd` using `returnFirst` and `returnNext`, it seems that for some function `f` in `fmap f db`, `f` is applied to the first field in each node only once - like I set out to do. But I can't seem to grasp how this is possible.

My intuition is telling me that the lazy nature of Haskell is coming into play here. Any insight or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

```
module DoubleList where

    data DoubleList a
        = LeftEnd  a (DoubleList a)
        | Middle   a (DoubleList a) (DoubleList a)
        | RightEnd a (DoubleList a)

    -- perserve identity
    -- fmap id create = id create
    -- perserve function composition
    -- fmap (f . g) create = fmap f . fmap g $ create
    instance Functor DoubleList where
        fmap f (LeftEnd a nxt) = LeftEnd (f a) (fmap f nxt)
        fmap f (Middle a prev nxt) = Middle (f a) (fmap f prev) (fmap f nxt)
        fmap f (RightEnd a prev) = RightEnd (f a) (fmap f prev)
    
    instance Show a =>  Show (DoubleList a) where 
        show (LeftEnd x next) = "Left End " ++ show x ++ "<->" ++ show next
        show (Middle x prev next) = show x ++ "<->" ++ show next
        show (RightEnd x next) = show x  ++ " Right End"
    
    create :: DoubleList Integer
    create = let n1 = LeftEnd  1 n2
                 n2 = Middle   2 n1 n3
                 n3 = Middle   3 n2 n4
                 n4 = Middle   4 n3 n5
                 n5 = RightEnd 5 n4
              in n1

    returnFirst :: DoubleList a -> DoubleList a
    returnFirst (Middle _ prev _) = returnFirst prev
    returnFirst (RightEnd _ prev) = returnFirst prev 
    returnFirst firstNode = firstNode

    returnPrev :: DoubleList a -> DoubleList a
    returnPrev (Middle x fst@(LeftEnd _ _) _ ) = fst
    returnPrev (Middle x mid@(Middle _ _ _) _ ) = mid
    returnPrev (RightEnd x prev) = prev
    returnPrev leftEnd = leftEnd

    returnNext :: DoubleList a -> DoubleList a
    returnNext (LeftEnd x nxt) = nxt
    returnNext (Middle x prev nxt) = nxt
    returnNext (RightEnd _ prev) =  prev
```

Comment: Since two consecutive nodes refer to each other, you can not just recurse on the two, since that would mean that it results in infinite recursion. But yes, lazyness means it will only `fmap f prev`, etc. on demand.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks, @WillemVanOnsem!  I was expecting a comment/response from you! haha.

Comment: "is applied only once" what do you mean by that? how exactly are you checking this and  what are you observing?

Comment: @WillNess, `returnFirst $ returnNext $ returnNext $ fmap (+1) create` results in `Left End 2<->3<->4<->5<->6 Right End`. `f` is applied to each node's value field only once.  My recursive definition of `fmap` made me think it would be possible that `(+1)` could be applied to each node more than once.

Comment: I feel it's important to point out that this isn't really a typical doubly linked list.  It's more like some sort of weird infinite tree (due to Haskell's immutability and implicit recursive nature of `let`).  If you want to see your `fmap (+1)` acting "more than once", try doing `returnFirst $ returnNext $ returnPrev $ returnNext $ returnPrev $ returnNext $ ...` or something similar.

Comment: please ask a specific question based on a specific piece of code, test call, and its output -- actual and expected. put this in the body of the post please.

Comment: @DDub I think the list defined by `create` is the usual doubly-linked list. it does have the proper sharing of nodes.

Comment: You might find [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28243314/791604) interesting reading. In particular it discusses ways in which you can have two different "shapes" of objects in memory that appear identical to all pure observations. That's what's happening to you: you have an object which appears to all pure observations to be a suitably `fmap`'d doubly linked list, but is actually an infinitely large tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
instance Functor DoubleList where
    fmap f (LeftEnd a nxt) = LeftEnd (f a) (fmap f nxt)
    fmap f (Middle a prev nxt) = Middle (f a) (fmap f prev) (fmap f nxt)
    fmap f (RightEnd a prev) = RightEnd (f a) (fmap f prev)
```

Each call to a constructor represents a new node, and each call to `fmap` represents a separate traversal over the data structure. In your definition of `create`, you use `let` bindings to ensure that the nodes are shared, but your definition of `fmap` doesn’t preserve that sharing. However, you can’t actually *observe* this from normal safe code.

The reason it works is that the fields of your data structure are lazy, so your `fmap` can produce a result incrementally: pattern-matching on the result of `fmap f create` just evaluates up to the constructor (`LeftEnd` / `Middle` / `RightEnd`) and doesn’t evaluate the fields. This means that even though `create` contains reference cycles, you won’t run into an infinite loop when mapping a function over it and examining the results.

The reason it *doesn’t* quite work is that it duplicates work. If it could preserve the sharing in the input, the result would be structured like this:

```
fmap f create
===
let n1' = LeftEnd  (f 1) n2'
    n2' = Middle   (f 2) n1' n3'
    n3' = Middle   (f 3) n2' n4'
    n4' = Middle   (f 4) n3' n5'
    n5' = RightEnd (f 5) n4'
in n1'
```

But as it is, it’s structured like this:

```
let n1' = LeftEnd  (f 1) n2'
    n2' = Middle   (f 2) (fmap f n1) (fmap f n3)
in n1'
```

Notice that `n2'` doesn’t contain any reference to the new `n1'`, it contains a thunk that will construct a value that happens to be equivalent to `n1'`. So what you’ve written is a valid `Functor` instance, but it will perhaps use more memory than you expected, depending on how you traverse the results. This data structure isn’t really a doubly-linked list, it’s a (possibly infinite) tree of computations, where each node may have 1 or 2 children.

By factoring, it’s equivalent to this, which you can think of as a type of infinite streams of values that may split into two at each point:

```
-- An infinite <3 -ary tree.
data LoveTree a
  = LoveTree a (These (LoveTree a) (LoveTree a))

-- Using ‘Data.These.These’:
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b
```